# How do you do mobile app cross platform payment?

Tags: google-play, app-store

When a user buys a subscription on CH Play, can I use the server to verify and then update the subscription on the iOS App side and vice versa?

However, Apple has a policy stating that: `Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase - Your app unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store, which is not appropriate for the App Store`.

That means the user has to buy again.

So How should I do mobile app cross platform payment?

Should I create a lot of offer codes?

Or refunding the user after buying twice is still a solution?

Answer (score -1):

> That means the user has to buy again.

No, you can buy subscription from Android or web and when you login into your account on iOS device you will find your subscription active. this is do not violate Apple's Guidelines (e.g. Spotify is doing this)

You should handle the subscription from server side to verify if the subscription paid on the original platform.

**UPDATE:**

> [3.1.3(b) Multiplatform Services:](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#multiplatform-services) Apps that operate across multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or features they have acquired in your app on other platforms or your web site, including consumable items in multi-platform games, provided those items are also available as in-app purchases within the app.

Comment: Spotify is selling songs not additional functionality. So they can ignore Appstore in-app purchase use whatever payment methods. Look at Epic Games Fortnite.

Comment: @KimMỹ Your interpretation of the guidelines is not accurate, see my update